# daemonize-liquidsoap.sh not working

Tags: raspberry-pi, streaming, raspberry-pi3, raspbian, liquidsoap

I've followed instructions here about installing liquid soap:

https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/creating-internet-radio-station-icecast-and-liquidsoap

This part I'm falling into difficulty:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/savonet/liquidsoap-daemon
$ cd liquidsoap-daemon
$ ./daemonize-liquidsoap.sh
```

It all works apart from:

```
$ ./daemonize-liquidsoap.sh
```

which produces:

```
Couldn't find a script at main, /home/radio/liquidsoap-daemon/script/main or /home/radio/liquidsoap-daemon/script/main.liq
```

Here is the list of folder /home/radio/liquidsoap-daemon:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  504 CHANGES
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3619 daemonize-liquidsoap.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1409 liquidsoap.initd.in
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  541 liquidsoap.launchd.in
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  326 liquidsoap.systemd.in
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1187 opam
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1922 README.md
```

What am I doing wrong?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You are missing the script at `/home/radio/liquidsoap-daemon/script/main`

Create the folder `script` at `/home/radio/liquidsoap-daemon/` and the file `main.liq` with e.g. `output.dummy(blank())` in it.